# SwiftUI redraw view during animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want a view (simplified example below) to animate through a value change by redrawing the entire view without the swiftui default interpolation. Moving the slide from 10 to 100 looks good. I want the animation to do the same.

Instead of fading in all view I the view to draw each step separately during the animation time.

I tried custom animations with and without keyframes and custom transitions but I couldn't get the result I wanted.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SampleView: View {

    private let value: Int

    init(value: Double) {
        self.value = Int(max(min(value, 1.0), 0.0) * 100)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            ForEach(0 ..< 101) { value in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(color(for: value))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 6.0)
                    .opacity(value < self.value ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            }
        }
    }

    private func color(for value: Int) -> Color {
        switch value % 4 {
        case 0: return Color.red
        case 1: return Color.blue
        case 2: return Color.yellow
        case 3: return Color.green
        default: return Color.black
        }
    }

}

#Preview("Interactive Sample") {
    struct InteractiveTestView: View {

        @State var value: Double = 0.1

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("\(Int(value * 100))%").font(.largeTitle)
                Button("Set to max") {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5.0)) {
                        value = 0.9
                    }
                }
                Slider(value: $value, in: 0.0...1.0, step: 0.01).padding()
                SampleView(value: value)
            }
        }

    }

    return InteractiveTestView()
}
```

Comment: I don't get what it is you want exactly. Could you explain yourself better? I've tried your code. You want the animation to execute when moving the slider?

Comment: @MatBuompy No, the slider is working as expected. The rectangles appear one after another as the user slides the slider. When animating using "Set to max" however, all the rectangles fade in all at once, instead of appearing one after another, like when using the slider.

Comment: @Sweeper ok I get it. Well, you solved it already. I tried your soution and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would change both `SampleView` and `InteractiveTestView` to have the same semantics for `value`, i.e. `value` should be a number between 0 and 100.

Then, you can just conform `SampleView` to `Animatable`.

```
struct InteractiveTestView: View {
    @State var value: Double = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(Int(value))%").font(.largeTitle)
            Button("Set to max") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5.0)) {
                    value = 99
                }
            }
            Slider(value: $value, in: 0.0...100.0, step: 1).padding()
            SampleView(value: value)
        }
    }
    
}
struct SampleView: View, Animatable {
    
    var value: Double
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            ForEach(0 ..< 101) { value in
                let diff = self.value - Double(value)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(color(for: value))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 6.0)
                    .opacity(Double(value) < self.value ? 1.0 : 0.0)                        
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func color(for value: Int) -> Color {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

Now the rectangles appear one after another during the animation.

If you also want them to fade in, use a continuous function for `opacity`:

```
.opacity(max(min(diff + 1, 1), 0))
```

Comment: I swear to god that I already tried that and it didn't work. Well it works, probably I had something a little bit different. Thank you!